# Django: custom template filter

Tags: django, templates, filter

How can i create a simple filter to extract values from a dictionary like this:

```
PHANTOM_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Type 1'),
    (2, 'Type 2'),
)
```

that works with django 1.4:

I've tried this:

```
from django.template import Library    
register = Library() 
    ...

def get(d, key):
    return d.get(key, '')

register.filter(key)
```

..but it doesn't work!
(it gives me the following error: 'function' object has no attribute 'filter')

Any ideas?

Comment: Your dictionary (`PHANTOM_TYPE_CHOICES`) isn't a dictionary but a tuple. And therefore there is no key. What are you trying to do with your filter?

Comment: I was trying to print any value of PHANTOM_TYPE_CHOICES in a template, using the corresponding index.. since in my database i've just memorized the indexes and not the description.

Comment: If you need a dict like access to your choices tuple you should convert it first: `dict(PHANTOM_TYPE_CHOICE)`. Now you should be able get your values via index. But if you just need the values for certain instances [`get_FOO_choices()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) might be enough.

Comment: nice trick, i didn't know we could make a conversione like that..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
register.filter('key', get)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code example you are trying to register a filter pointing to the method "key" however the method's name is "get"

Replace

```
register.filter(key)
```

with

```
register.filter(get)
```

or use the decorator

```
@register.filter()
def get(d, key):
    return dict(d).get(key, '')
```

Comment: it's strange but it keeps giving me the error:

...'function' object has no attribute 'filter'

.seems that 'filter' method it's not a valid method!!

Comment: Have you tried renaming the method to something else than get()? Maybe that is causing some strange behavior.

Comment: yes, and maybe there will be a django malfunction or missconfiguration, i think!

Comment: I added arie's solution to convert the tuple to a dict first. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: all the problem is at this instruction: 
"register.filter(get)"

When, I just try to load one of my urls, it shows me the error related to that line: "'function' object has no attribute 'filter'"

Maybe you can try it for me: Just copy/paste the function (include the libs).. and see if you get any error, just loading one of your pages (without modifying any template).

Comment: How is the filter used in the template? When adding the code above I get it to work. When removing the dict(d), I get "'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: DICTIONARY=PHANTOM_TYPE_CHOICES I assume. Where does key_dict come from?

Comment: yes: DICTIONARY=PHANTOM_TYPE_CHOICES. key_dict comes from another integer object used in the template. BUt instead you can use the values: 1 or 2.

Comment: Hm, nope I can't recreate that. If you open a python command prompt can you do the from django.template import Library

Comment: ..but at least you don't get any error related to the "filter" method?

Comment: I would guess that you have a class in models or somewhere else in the project path that has a class named Library. That is why you get it. I tried to create one myself and was able to recreate it. Maybe you are doing a from models import * or similar and then get a reference to a different Library class.

Comment: emm, I would check for it. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: OK cool, let me know if that was the case so we can add this as an answer to the question.